# How to prevent screen saver from preventing Zoom meeting from starting?

Tags: screensaver, zoom.app

I'm not really sure if this is a Zoom issue or a Mac issue but maybe someone else knows.

I have regular Zoom sessions several times per week.  I usually fire up my computer ahead of time and sign into the room so I can't forget, then let the screen saver kick in.  The trouble is, if the screen saver is running when the meeting begins, Zoom will not actually start until I activate the computer and disable the screen saver.  Then it suddenly signs into the room and everything is fine.

Is there any way to prevent this?  I was hoping that the meeting starting would just kick the mac into action and I'd hear the meeting start.

Comment: Is just the screensaver running or is the Mac at sleep?

Comment: Screensaver not sleep